# How to remove old virtual environment paths on the select interpreter list in VSCode

Tags: ubuntu, visual-studio-code, ide, virtual-environment

I am familiarizing working with Django virtual environments in VSCode. Created a couple of virtual environments, some are no longer but I still can see them listed in the select interpreter section.

How can I remove, or clean up this list?

I have tried to right click on a specific path but the select interpreter window closes immediately with no further options.

Comment: Not sure what this command does, but maybe give it a try?: "Python: Clear Workspace Interpreter Setting"

Comment: This command clears the entire list.

Comment: huh. and what happens if you restart VS Code after that? Does anything get re-populated?